# JavaScript call function inside a function by variable name

Tags: javascript, function, object, dynamic

I'm having a difficulty calling a function inside of another function when its name is in a variable:

```
var obj = {}

obj.f = function() {
  var inner = {
    a: function() {
      function b() {
        alert('got it!');
      }
      b(); // WORKS AS EXPECTED
      x = 'b';
      [x](); // DOESN'T WORK, NEITHER this[x]() window[x](), etc.
    }
  }
  inner.a();
}

obj.f();
```

I tried prefixing `[x]()` with different scope paths but so far w/o success. Searching existing answers did not turn up anything. It works with `this[x]()` if `b()` is placed directly inside object inner. I would like to keep `b()` as a function inside `function a()` because of variable scope in `function a()`, otherwise I would need to pass many parameters to `b()`.

////
Re duplicate question: Quentin provided a more elegant answer in this thread imo.

Comment: try `window[x].apply(this, [param1, param2])` [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: @RaraituL `b` will be scoped so you can't do this

Comment: @PaulS. The way `x` is defined, it will be created under `window` object

Comment: so you want call what function where?

Comment: @RaraituL — `x` will be but `b` won't. It is `window['b']` that doesn't exist, not `x`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no sensible way of accessing an arbitrary variable using a string matching the name of the variable. (For a very poor way to do so, see `eval`).

> `[x]();` // DOESN'T WORK

You're trying to call an array as a function

> NEITHER `this[x]()`

The function isn't a property of the `inner` object.

> `window[x]()`, etc.

Since it isn't a global, it isn't a property of the window object either.

---

If you need to call a function based on the value of a string variable, then organise your functions in an object and access them from that.

```
  function b() {
    alert('got it!');
  }
  var myFunctions = {
      b: b
  };
  x = 'b';
  myFunctions[x]();
```

Comment: var myFunctions = {
      b: b
  };

That did it!

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Currently you are assigning string to variable x, instead of a function variable.

```
 x = b;
 x();
```

Comment: perhaps it could have worked if value b were assigned directly. it comes from a calculation. it's not real code in the example.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your assignment

use `x = b` instead of `x = 'b'` to assign the function object as the latter just assigns the string into x.

Once you fix your assignment you can invoke the function as

```
x();
a.x();
a[x]();
```

etc.

Comment: you have to change the `a[x]()`, to `a["x"]();`, unless x is a string variable with `"x"` value in it.

Answer (score 2):

You should make array for the function and then access using name in your variable as follow:

```
var obj = {}

obj.f = function() {
  var inner = {
    a: function() {
      // set up the possible functions:
      var myFuncs = {
              b: function b() {alert('got it!');}
              };
      //b(); // WORKS AS EXPECTED --> commented this code
      x = 'b';
      myFuncs[x]();    
    }
  }
  inner.a();
}
```

Comment: @Gonki you need minimum changes in your code for this solution

Answer (score 1):

The *function declaration* `b` will be captured in the closure of the *anonymous function expression* assigned as `a`.

1. When `var` is used in a closure, there is no (available in *JavaScript*) *Object* which gets assigned a property similar to what happens with `window` in the *Global Scope*.
2. Writing a function declaration effectively `var`s the *name* of the *function*.

If you really want to access a variable (i.e. `b`) by *String*, you will either need to create an *Object* which holds `b` similar to what you've done for `a`, or (and possibly dangerously) rely on an `eval` to convert `"b"` to `b`.

If you can't create the whole *Object* ahead-of-time, you can use this format

```
/* in (higher?) scope */
var fnRef = {};
// now when you
function b() {/* define as desired */}
// also keep a ref.
fnRef['b'] = b;
// fnRef['b']() will work **after this line**
```

Answer (score 1):

let's say your code is like this:

```
//instead of x = 'b'
x = function(){}
```

then your solution could be like this:

```
var obj = {}

obj.f = function() {
  var inner = {
    a: function() {
      function b() {
        alert('got it!');
      }
      b(); // WORKS AS EXPECTED
      //you can define it as a variable
      var x = function(){};
      //and call it like this
      x();

      //or define it like this
      this[x] = function(){};
      //and call it like this
      this[x]();

      //but you are creating an array [x] which is not a function
      //and you are trying to call an array????
      [x](); // DOESN'T WORK, NEITHER this[x]() window[x](), etc.
    }
  }
  inner.a();
}

obj.f();
```