# JavaScript - Call a function by a string

Tags: javascript

This question is already existing in a different way, but my code is mostly different so I dont get the solution out of the other answers. That's a example Code:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/e52n28xs/
```

I want start the function like this:

```
var test1 = {
    start: function() { }
};
var fn = 'test1';
fn.start();
```

I know the following works, but I need the string option.

```
test1.start();
```

Maybe that's impossible?

Comment: If `test1` is in the global scope, you could do `window[fn]()`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you’re planning on having a sequence of `test1..n`, use an array instead.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496961/call-a-javascript-function-name-using-a-string. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089524/javascript-call-function-inside-a-function-by-variable-name. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202942/javascript-dynamic-function-call-with-name.

Comment: use eval: `(new Function(fn+'.start'))();`

Comment: Can you wrap `test1` in a context, e.g. `var ctx = { test1: { start: function() {} }`? Then it would be `ctx['test1'].start();`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Depending on the value of `this` in the function you run this, either of these will work:

```
window['test1'].start();
```

Or

```
this['test1'].start();
```

Obviously, you can do the same with the function name itself, example:

```
test1['start']();
```

or

```
this['test1']['start']();
// same as:     var test1 = this['test1']; test1['start']();
```

If you want the whole thing to be string, then:

```
eval('test1.start()');
```

That would also work if you are using `var`, where in the previous string versions you'd have to have a container object to query.

Comment: for use it you should `this.test1 = ...;`, not `var test1 = ...;`

Comment: Is there some particular reason that I should use `test['start']()` instead of `test.start()`? Would you suggesting putting up alerts by calling `window['alert']("Hi")`?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest doing this most of the time, unless the function name is reserved word and you need to support IE8, or for some reason the function name itself is dynamic (you can put any string variable in there not just static string). I just thought if the OP wants the object to be string he might want the function too.

Comment: @torazaburo, if you have function name in string argument, for example

Comment: For the `this` vs `var`, I already mentioned it depends on the context.

Comment: And added a note on it in the last line as well.

Comment: Then you need the `test1['start']();` example from my answer

Comment: Ah no, I mean the first name is dynamic. start() is everytime the same. It's not everytime test1, maybe its tree52, car22, flower5 and so on.

Comment: If so, two options: either `eval('test1').start()`, or else you need to have some container that has all the objects like `var stuff = { test1: test1, tree52: tree52 };` and then you can use something like `stuff['test1'].start()`. Both options were explained in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with `eval()` function

```
var test1 = {
    start: function() { }
};
var fn = 'test1';
eval(fn).start()
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/s70z38ys/)

Comment: Why a downvote ??? Explain !

Comment: If the answer is `eval`, you don't understand the question. P.S. Not the down-voter. P.P.S. I know there are some places where `eval` is the only option, but this shouldn't be one of them.

Comment: Not me, but `eval is evil`, we don't like it ever :)

Comment: This answer obvious, all know it :)